# Wait for the whole omp block to be finished before calling the second function

Tags: c++, openmp

I don't have experience with openmp in C++ and I would like to learn how to solve my problem properly. I have 30 files that need to be processed independently by the same function. Each time the function is activated, a new output file will be generated (out01.txt to out30.txt) saving the results. I have 12 processors in my machine and would like to use 10 for this problem.

I need to change my code to wait for all the 30 files to be processed to execute other routines in C++. At this moment, I'm not able to force my code to wait for all the omp scope to be executed and then move the second function.

Please find below a draft of my code.

```
   int W = 10; 
   int i = 1;
   ostringstream fileName;
   int th_id, nthreads;

        omp_set_num_threads(W);
        #pragma omp parallel shared (nFiles) private(i,fileName,th_id)
        {
             #pragma omp for schedule(static)
            for ( i = 1; i <= nFiles; i++)
            {
                th_id = omp_get_thread_num();
                 cout << "Th_id: " << th_id << endl;

            // CALCULATION IS PERFORMED HERE FOR EACH FILE

            }
        }

            // THIS is the point where the program should wait for the whole block to be finished
            // Calling the second function ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the "omp for" and "omp parallel" pragmas have an implicit barrier at the end of its scope. Therefore, the code after the parallel section can't be executed until the parallel section has concluded. So your code should run perfectly.

If there is still a problem then it isn't because your code isn't waiting at the end of the parallel region.

Please supply us with more details about what happens during execution of this code. This way we might be able to find the real cause of your problem.